# Passing data from one widget to another

Tags: flutter, flutter-widget

I have a list of choice widget and want to pass the selected choice to another widget.
Here is the list of choice widget

```
class ChoiceChipWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  final List<String> reportList;
  final Function(String item) onChoiceSelected;

  ChoiceChipWidget(this.reportList, this.onChoiceSelected);

  @override
  _ChoiceChipWidgetState createState() => new _ChoiceChipWidgetState();
}

class _ChoiceChipWidgetState extends State<ChoiceChipWidget> {
  String selectedChoice = "";

  _buildChoiceList() {
    List<Widget> choices = List();
    widget.reportList.forEach((item) {
      choices.add(Container(
        child: ChoiceChip(
          label: Text(item),
          selected: selectedChoice == item,
          onSelected: (selected) {
            setState(() {
              selectedChoice = item;
              widget.onChoiceSelected(item);
              print(selectedChoice); //DATA THAT NEEDS TO BE PASSED
            });
          },
        ),
      ));
    });
    return choices;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Wrap(
      children: _buildChoiceList(),
    );
  }
}
```

I need to pass it to this widget

```
class AddCashPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _AddCashPageState createState() => _AddCashPageState();
}

class _AddCashPageState extends State<AddCashPage> {

  void createTodo() async {
    if (_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
      _formKey.currentState.save();
      String repetition = //DATA NEEDS TO GO HERE;
      final addCash = AddCash(repetition);
      setState(() {
        id = addCash.id;
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Form(
        key: _formKey,
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                ChoiceChipWidget(chipList, (item) {
                  selectedItem = item;
                }),
              ],
            ),
            RaisedButton(
              child: Text("Update Cash Flow"),
              onPressed: createTodo,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I tried making a constructor inside `AddCashPage`
like this

```
class AddCashPage extends StatefulWidget {
  final ChoiceChipWidget choiceChipWidget;

  AddCashPage({Key key, @required this.choiceChipWidget}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _AddCashPageState createState() => _AddCashPageState();
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you just missed to call setState() in here:

```
  ChoiceChipWidget(chipList, (item) {
          selectedItem = item;
        }),
```

Like this:

```
  ChoiceChipWidget(chipList, (item) {
          setState(() => selectedItem = item);
        }),
```

Then you could do this:

```
AddCash(selectedItem)
```

Make sure to declare the `selectedItem` variable inside `_AddCashPageState`, I don't see it on your code.

Answer (score 2):

Your choice widget passes the data to the AddCashPage via the constructor you created, but you're missing something. You need to pass the data that AddCashPage has to its state (_AddCashState) so that you can use it there. Basically, you need to create one more constructor.

```
class AddCashPage extends StatefulWidget {
  final ChoiceChipWidget choiceChipWidget;

  AddCashPage({Key key, @required this.choiceChipWidget}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _AddCashPageState createState() => _AddCashPageState(choiceChipWidget: choiceChipWidget);
}
```

And in _AddCashPageState:

```
class _AddCashPageState extends State<AddCashPage> {
   final choiceChipWidget;
   _AddCashPageState({Key key, @required this.choiceChipWidget});
}
```

Comment: Or you can use the **choiceChipWidget** in _AddCashPageState as **widget.choiceChipWidget**, as Jay Mungara said.

Comment: `choiceChipWidget` under  `_AddCashPageState` returns null

Answer (score 2):

To use your passed data inside **_AddCashPageState** class you can use widget property of the corresponding state of the related Stateful class.

For Ex : To use choice chip widget in your  class you can use it like **widget.ChoiceChipWidget**

Any **properties/methods** provided in **AddCashPage** class can be accessed in its State class **_AddCashPageState()** using **widget.ChoiceChipWidget** property;

You can use this **widget** property inside methods only like, **initState()**, **build()**, **dispose()** etc.

Comment: I don't want to use the choice widget itself. I want to use the data `selectedChoice`  from that widget. and pass it to `_AddCashPageState`. Specifically add it to `String repetition = //PASS selectedChoice` here

Comment: Then you should pass only selectedChoice in the constructor and fetch data in State class using widget.selectedChoice